# EWS - appointment.body created by outlook365 client returns empty

Tags: calendar, exchangewebservices, appointment

I have a problem: cannot get appointment body if it was created by outlook365 client.
When i run the code all properties values are being received except body.

After some searching i've found out that appointment bodies are not being received if appointments were made by outlook365. 
Please, help!

The code:

```cs
    public static List<Appointment> SetupConnection()
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CallbackMethods.CertificateValidationCallBack;
                ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
                service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("Someuser@somedomain.com", "SomePassword");
                service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
                Folder calendarFolder = GetCalendarFolder(service, @"\");
                return GetMeetings(calendarFolder, service);

        }
    public static List<Appointment> GetMeetings(Folder calendarFolder, ExchangeService service)
        {
             if (calendarFolder == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection filters = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And)
            {
                new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(AppointmentSchema.Start, DateTime.Today)
            };

            List<Appointment> meetings = new List<Appointment>();
            const Int32 pageSize = 30;
            ItemView itemView = new ItemView(pageSize);
            PropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
            itemView.PropertySet = propertySet;

            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = null;
            do
            {
                findResults = calendarFolder.FindItems(filters, itemView);
                itemView.Offset += pageSize;
                meetings.AddRange(findResults.Cast<Appointment>());
            } while (findResults.MoreAvailable);


            PropertySet propertySet1 = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
            propertySet1.Add(ItemSchema.Body);
            propertySet1.Add(ItemSchema.Subject);
            propertySet1.Add(AppointmentSchema.Organizer);
            propertySet1.Add(AppointmentSchema.Start);
            propertySet1.Add(AppointmentSchema.End);
            propertySet1.Add(AppointmentSchema.Duration);
            propertySet1.Add(AppointmentSchema.AppointmentType);
            propertySet1.Add(AppointmentSchema.ConferenceType);
            propertySet1.Add(AppointmentSchema.IsOnlineMeeting);
            propertySet1.Add(AppointmentSchema.IsMeeting);
            propertySet1.Add(AppointmentSchema.IsRecurring);
            propertySet1.Add(AppointmentSchema.HasAttachments);
            propertySet1.Add(AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees);
            propertySet1.Add(AppointmentSchema.Resources);
            propertySet1.Add(AppointmentSchema.InternetMessageHeaders);
            propertySet1.RequestedBodyType = Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType.Text;
            service.LoadPropertiesForItems(meetings, propertySet1);

            return meetings;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only returning `IdOnly`

Try changing `BasePropertySet.IdOnly` to `BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties`